# call page which use htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have htaccess file and this is in it:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /project/

RewriteRule ^betNow/$ index.php?action=betNow [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/betNow/$ index.php?action=betNow [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/betNow/([0-9]+)$ index.php?action=betNow&id=$2 [L]
```

and it works, when I type localhost/project/betNow/
but I can't figure out last rule
I tried with localhost/project/betNow/4
and localhost/project/betNow/id=4
and that's not working. what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Tip: You may want to add /? by the end of the regexp so you don't get errors when people type (or don't type) slash at the end of the URL. So it becomes: ^(.*)/betNow/([0-9]+)/?$ -- Adjust to the answers further down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined your `RewriteBase /project/` and your site apparently resides in `http://localhost/project/` - so when you call `http://localhost/project/betNow/` the request string handed over to the rewrite rules is just `betNow/`.

Therefor your rules starting with `^(.*)/betNow` will not match. You just need:

```
RewriteRule ^betNow/$ index.php?action=betNow [L]
RewriteRule ^betNow/([0-9]+)$ index.php?action=betNow&id=$2 [L]
```

And you can use

```
http://localhost/project/betNow/  --> index.php?action=betNow
http://localhost/project/betNow/4 --> index.php?action=betNow&id=4
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't the rules be

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /project/

RewriteRule ^betNow/$ index.php?action=betNow [L]
RewriteRule ^betNow/([0-9]+)$ index.php?action=betNow&id=$2 [L]
```

You may need to put a `/` after both of the `^` characters in the rewrite rules too

Answer (score 1):

Instead of localhost/project/betNow/id=4 try: localhost/project/betNow/id/4

And use:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/betNow/id/([0-9]+)$ index.php?action=betNow&id=$2 [L]
```